# Why this python-2.7 test case return True?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

```
def antisymmetric(A):
    #Write your code here
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if  A[i][j] == -A[j][i]:
                return True
            else:
                return False    


# Test Cases:

print antisymmetric([[0, 1, 2], 
                     [-1, 0, -2], 
                     [2, 2,  3]])
#>>> False
```

Surprisingly the above test case return True for this python 2.7 coding, Can anyone tell me the reason ?

Comment: Because the first thing's 0.

Comment: 0 == -0 and the world works as expected.

Comment: A[0][0] == -A[0][0], because A[0][0] == 0

Comment: When `return` statement is hit, your function will terminate. Essentially it compares the first pair of cells (0.0 and 0.0) and returns result based on that.

Comment: Even though I got negative points,  would like to thanks for everyone especially  user5226582 ,Kalpesh Dusane and koster1889.

Answer (score 3):

It is returning  True at i = 0 and j =0

Modified solution:

```
def antisymmetric(A):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if  A[i][j] != -A[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test returns immediately after the first check. To test if the matrix is antisymmetric (skew-symmetric) you need to keep checking until you find a pair (i, j) with `A[i][j] != -A[j][i]`.

It's almost always better in Python to directly loop over the items in containers rather than using indices. To transpose the matrix we can use the built-in `zip` function:

```
def is_antisymmetric(m):
    # Transpose matrix m
    t = zip(*m)

    #Check each row against each column
    for row, col in zip(m, t):
        #Test that each item in the row is the negative 
        # of the corresponding column item
        for u, v in zip(row, col):
            if u != -v:
                return False
    return True

# Test

data = (
    # Not anti-symmetric
    [[0, 1, 2],
    [-1, 0, -2],
    [2, 2, 3]],

    # Anti-symmetric
    [[0, 1, 2],
    [-1, 0, -2],
    [-2, 2, 0]],
)

for m in data:
    for row in m:
        print(row)
    print(is_antisymmetric(m))
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2]
[-1, 0, -2]
[2, 2, 3]
False
[0, 1, 2]
[-1, 0, -2]
[-2, 2, 0]
True
```

We can make the function much more compact by using a generator expression inside the `all` function:

```
def is_antisymmetric(m):
    return all([-u for u in col] == row for row, col in zip(m, zip(*m)))
```

The `all` function stops testing as soon as it finds a row that's not equal to the corresponding column. And the `==` test also stops comparing the current row with the current column as soon as it finds a mismatch, so this code is equivalent to the earlier version, except that it's a little more efficient. However, it may not be so easy to read if you're not used to generator expressions. :)

FWIW, all of the code in this answer runs on Python 2 and Python 3, and it handles square matrices of any size.

Answer (score 1):

You return True at i=0 j=0 the loop are not executed until the end

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because you return from the function after the first test.
You would probably want to return only after you can rule out the possibility of the matrix being antisymmetric. Ie. onley return false within the loop, and return true after the loops have run through.

Comment: You should state your answer with more confidence! Don't say "I guess" and "probably". And use a spell-checker. :)